# How to add more workspaces in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, lxde

I'm on Lubuntu 14.04 and using it on a bootable USB drive. How do I add more workspaces? Right now there are two workspaces, but those were there by default. Do I have to download additional software to manage the workspaces?

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you can add more workspaces!

Follow this steps:

1. Click on the "Lubuntu" icon in the bottom of the screen;
2. Set **Preferences**>>**Openbox Configuration Manager**
3. On the new window opened, click on "**Desktop"** option;
4. On the field labeled "**Number of desktops**" you can choose how many
   workspaces do you need.
5. After all, just close the window.

**Good luck, man!**

Comment: Note for users that have installed Openbox later: You may need to run `sudo apt-get install obconf` if the menu option is missing.

Comment: @André OP may be a woman, man!

Answer (score 7):

I use this command:

```
wmctrl -n 4
```

it means: Make 4 desktops. Read man page for more info. It is quite useful program.

Comment: Specifically, it means set the total number of desktops to 4. Also, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add ppa:geod/ppa-geod to your Software sources then:

> sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces

Start managing workspaces from indicator-workspaces

Comment: This PPA only supports up to 11.04, OP indicated he was using 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Start command line (or hit on alt-F2) and enter "obconf" (without quotations). Click on "Desktops" and choose the number of desktops that you want. In addition, by double clicking Desktops name, you can rename Desktops as desired.